# Google map api v3 - only show capital city name - London - not boroughs

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know how to display only the capital city on a customised map e.g London ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a KML Layer (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) and do not want Infowindows you need to use the

```
suppressInfoWindows
```

option.

It looks like this:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.insideoutdigital.com/map/Clients3.kml', 
    { suppressInfoWindows: true });
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

There is no generic way. You would need to set the label to off for all localities using a styled map with:

```
style = [
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]

var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      ...
      styles: styles
};

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  }
```

and then geocode and display a label for capital cities yourself by geocoding the location or providing it yourself.

You can use the MapLabel library to draw a nice looking label:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/docs/reference.html

Check out this demo on how to use the maplabel library:
http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/demos/directions/directions2.html

HTH

Comment: Hi, also, is it possible to disable infoWindows so that when a marker is clicked they do not appear?

Comment: i can't seem to login to see that url

Comment: sooory ... the right one is: http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/demos/marker/single.html , do you have a sample that shows a clickable marker ?

Comment: ah! you are using KML ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers  let me fix the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks. yes, KML. I cannot for the life of me, work out how to disable the infoWindows

Comment: look at the top , the answer is there:   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.insideoutdigital.com/map/Clients3.kml', 
    { suppressInfoWindows: true });
ctaLayer.setMap(map);